# Haskell - Num vs Double, Int types

Tags: haskell, types

Haskell noob here.

Im trying to make the following function and this error is extremely cryptic to me:

```
:{
myfunc::(Double a)=> a -> a -> a
myfunc a b = a + b
:}
```

and I get:

```
error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Double’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature: myfunc :: (Double a) => a -> a -> a
```

The same goes for Int.

However, it I use Num type, I get no error:

```
:{
myfunc::(Num a)=> a -> a -> a
myfunc a b = a+b
:}
```

The same goes if I use just plain Int or Double without Double a

```
:{
myfunc::Double -> Double -> Double
myfunc a b = a+b
:}
```

My question:
How come is it, that I can use Num a, or just plan Double, Int, but I cannot use Double a, or Int a?

Regards.

Comment: `Double` is a type, `Num` is a typeclass (a "group" of types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a terminology note: when GHC writes `*` here in the error messages, read it as [`Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type), the *kind of types*<sup>†</sup>. It is for historical reasons that older versions of GHC write it with the asterisk symbol.

So, your error message is

```
    • Expected kind ‘Type -> Constraint’, but ‘Double’ has kind ‘Type’
    • In the type signature: myfunc :: (Double a) => a -> a -> a
```

Ok, `‘Double’ has kind ‘Type’` – that should make enough sense, right? `Double` *is* a type.

But why does it say it's “expecting” `Type -> Constraint`? Well, it means you tried to use `Double` as if it were of this kind. Namely, you wrote `Double a`. Here, `a` has to be a type, but you can't apply a type to another type, that would be like applying a character to a character on the value level:

```
Prelude> 'x' 'y'

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> t’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • The function ‘'x'’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘Char’ has none
```

By contrast, `Num` is a *type class*, and as such it has in fact the correct kind:

```
Prelude> :k Num
Num :: Type -> Constraint
```

`Constraint` is the correct kind that's expected on the left of the `=>`, so that's why you can write

```
myfunc :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Again, `Double` is a type, not a type class, so it can't be used in this way. However, what you can use is an *equality constraint*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

myfunc :: a~Double => a -> a -> a
myfunc = (+)
```

This is effectively the same as

```
myfunc :: Double -> Double -> Double
```

(there are some subtle differences with respect to typechecking).

Vice versa, it is not possible to write

```
myfunc :: Num -> Num -> Num
myfunc = (+)

error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Num’
      Expected a type, but ‘Num’ has kind ‘Type -> Constraint’
    • In the type signature: myfunc :: Num -> Num -> Num
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>To be completely precise, `Type` is the kind of *lifted types*. Don't worry about what that means: unless you're doing very low-level stuff, you may never need to work with unlifted types.</sub>

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thank you for this very comprehensive answer. And thanx for pointing out how to read '*' (as Type).

Comment: "there are some subtle differences with respect to typechecking" -- are any of them externally visible, i.e. can I as a user of GHC observe the difference without modifying GHC's source?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm actually not sure whether it makes any observable difference to typechecking outside. (Unlike of course in instance heads, where `a~Double` has a very different effect). But what _is_ different is that because `a~Double` is technically polymorphic, it can't be a CAF, which can make a performance difference. E.g. ``myfunc = let a = sum [9 | n <- [0..1000000], n`mod`345 == 0] in \x y -> x*y+a`` will compute `a` only once if the signature is `Double -> Double -> Double`, but computes it anew with every call if the signature is `a~Double => a->a->a`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah, excellent, the CAF distinction is very convincing. Thanks for pointing that out, it's a language corner I will have to remember! For example, in the past I have used `shortName ~ Very Long Type => ...` as a sort of local type alias; in the future I will know to watch out for whether this is introducing undesirable polymorphism.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Err... except it doesn't actually seem to be true? When I compile `x :: a ~ Double => a; x = sum [0..100000000]; main = print x >> print x` with `-O2`, there is a very visible pause followed by two instantaneous printouts. Similarly with your more complicated example with `let`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Interesting. Well, the optimiser apparently makes a “specialisation” for the `Double` case, which is sensible enough if it's literally the only possible specialisation! Still: with `x :: Double` signature you can actually _rely_ on shared values being kept, even in interpreted mode. Whereas with `a~Double -> a`, the optimiser needs to decide it's worthwhile. (I suppose you could nudge it with a `SPECIALIZE` pragma, but that seems a bit silly...)